# Laravel with SQL Server Eloquent Relationship with comma separated column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have DB with following tables. Products table has column name of outlet that is stored in comma separated outlet IDs. I need to achieve below mentioned results without using any raw queries. I am using **sql server**.

1.Outlets table
2.Products Table

[image: Products]

[image: Outlets]

I need to achieve below mentioned results without using any raw queries

```
{
  "outlet":1,
  "ShortName":"KPN-Mylapore",
  "Products":{
        "ProdId": 26,
    "ProdCode": 1, 
    "ProdName":"LEMON",
    "SRate":50.00,
    "ImgPath1":"images/product/Web/Lemon 01-1.jpg",
    "Scatid":2,
    "Mcatid":1
},
{
  "outlet":1,
  "ShortName":"KPN-Mylapore",
  "Products":{
        "ProdId": 1621,
    "ProdCode": 100010, 
    "ProdName":"3ROSES",
    "SRate":50.00,
    "ImgPath1":"images/product/Web/3ROSES 100G 01-100010.jpg",
    "Scatid":51,
    "Mcatid":8
}

}]
```

Comment: You are using very bad database design. Your outlet must not be comma separated. Normalize it and convert into many to many  or one to many relationship with different table.

Answer (score 0):

You should show us what you've tried already. But with the information I have now and assuming you set up relationships in your models, you could do something like below. Keep in mind that I do have very little information, I will update answer accordingly if necessary.

```
$result = Outlet::with('products')
                ->where('prodId', function ($query) {
                    $query->whereIn('prodId', [OUTLET_IDS_HERE]);
                })->get();
```